# How to Submit 0.4.10 Sol version Contracts to Etherscan for Verification

Tags: solidity, etherscan, contract-verification

I am trying to verify a Solidity Contract I wrote using Remix written in Solidity version 0.4.10.The problem is that Etherscan wont allow me to select Solidity Version 0.4.10 for my Project.

Comment: please share the contract

Comment: Contract Address: 0x399eE38451d868ceFf485B30aD94dc4a147b6E4A

Comment: Etherscan requires a file of original code for verification

Comment: Yes I uploaded all my Source code..
https://pastebin.com/DbEQErNG

Comment: link not working anyhow you can modify code version by this command pragma solidity <=0.5.0. This will work for any version less than 5 and you don't even have to change the code. Thanks

Comment: @Ninja Etherscan is a closed source third party block explorer. For this type of questions is better ask to their customer support. Also solc v0.4.10 is just too old and it has some serious bugs, you should not use it for production.